# Arrange elements of array into one column

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a  500x2 array with some data in Matlab

```
X1 X2
X3 X4
X5 X6
.....
```

I want to arrange it in an array with one column

```
 X1
 X2
 X3
 X4
 ..
```

Can someone give me some tips as to how it can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your array is called `X`:

```
Xt = X';            %'// Use X.' if you're dealing with complex numbers
Xcol = Xt(:)
```

Or else you could do

```
Xcol = reshape(X', [], 1)
```